# Laravel - Select only certain columns within a 'hasMany' query

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have a query that currently works, however, it returns significantly more data than what I need.

**Query**

```
$alerts = Criteria::with('coordinate', 'alerts')
        ->where('user_id', '=', Auth::id())
        ->get();
```

For example, if I want to only select the `viewed` column out of `alerts`, can this be achieved in this query. I've used `::with` to harness Laravel's eager loading feature.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use a closure to set the `SELECT` clause on your query:

```
$alerts = Criteria::with(['coordinate', 'alerts' => function($query)
{
    $query->select('id', 'coordinate_id', 'viewed');
}])
->where('user_id', '=', Auth::id())
->get();
```

Remember to include the foreign keys, so that Eloquent can properly map them for you.

Comment: Unfortunately I am presented with the error - `syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW)`.

Comment: @Ben - Whoops. Was missing the array `[]` brackets. Added them.